# session_start(): Cannot start session when headers already sent

Tags: php, php7

Recibo esta advertencia que no me permite continuar:

> Warning: session_start(): Cannot start session when headers already sent in C:\xampp\htdocs\bancoinfocial\index.php on line 45
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION in C:\xampp\htdocs\bancoinfocial\principal.php on line 3

Y éste es mi código:

index.php

```
<div id="principal" hidden>
    <?php
    session_start();
    require_once("principal.php");
    ?>
</div>
```

principal.php

```
<div>
<?php
echo $_SESSION['fullname'];
?>
</div>
```

Es decir, invoco a ***principal.php*** desde ***index.php*** en donde no se puede iniciar sesión por cabeceras ya enviadas aun siendo la primer instrucción que ejecuto en cada invocación del método `session_start()`.

Comment: Bienvenido! Seria útil que mostraras el código de los dos archivos.

Comment: Tienes un `<div>` antes del `session_start()`, entonces `session_start`no va a ser lo primero que se invoca.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo con Álvaro,  no puedes enviar nada al navegador antes de enviar las cabeceras y en el caso que expones estás enviado texto, un div en este caso, pero un espacio por ejemplo también podría causar el mismo problema. Por eso se recomienda llamar a `session_start()` al principio del **archivo**.

Comment: Si señores, a todos muchas gracias... efectivamente puse el llamado a session_start(); al principio de index.php, gracias

Comment: Crea un nuevo archivo y copia el contenido. El archivo se te corrompió

Comment: Tuve el mismo problema y era un simple espacio previo al llamado de la sesión... Muy buena la observación de otro compañero, porque no lo hubiera creido! Funciona así:
<?php session_start(); Pero de este modo no....
<?php session_start();

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[`session_start()`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.session-start.php) es una función que envía varias cabeceras HTTP dependiendo de la configuración, por eso no puede ejecutarse después de que se haya escrito contenido (porque entonces las cabeceras no se podrán modificar).

Tienes `<div>` en tu código HTML que preceden al `session_start`de PHP y eso es lo que te está causando el problema. `session_start` debería ir lo primero, antes de que se escriba nada. Así que debes moverlo al principio de todo para evitar ese error:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<div id="principal" hidden>
<?php
require_once("principal.php");
?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8):

El problema es porque estás haciendo un `div` en tu html antes de validar la sesión. En **PHP** el `session_start();` debe ir antes que cualquier otra cosa. Inclusive antes que el `div`.

Prueba con lo siguiente:

**index.php**

```
<?php
    session_start(); 
?>
<div id="principal" hidden>
    <?php
        require_once("principal.php");
    ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Para que funcione tienes que mover el session *session_start* al inicio del index.php.

**Index.php**

```
<?php
        session_start();
?>
<div id="principal" hidden>
    <? 
        $_SESSION['fullname'] = "Delcio";
        require_once("principal.php");
    ?>
</div>
```

**principal.php**

```
<div>
    <?php
        echo $_SESSION['fullname'];
    ?>
</div>
```

> Recuerda que para que pueda pintar en el div lo que tiene la variable de session 
>   $_SESSION['fullname']; debes quitar el hidden del div.

Answer (score 0):

Lo mismo me pasaba a mi, Intenten haciendo esto:

**solución 1**

```
if( !headers_sent() && '' == session_id() ) {
session_start();
}
```

sino te funciona puede ser que una función nativa que usas de php, Que este creando una session o algo por el estilo y no te permita incluir un archivo en mi caso era lo siguiente.

```
$foto = base64_encode($foto);
```

Este ("base64_encode()" no me permitía incluir un archivo con php donde iniciará una session.

**Soluccion 2**

la solución parece compleja pero no lo es, solo debes crear un contenedor donde vas a incluir todo, y lo incluyes con Javascript y ajax así:

```
//primero creas una función
function Incluir() {
//seleccionas el contenedor
var contenedor = document.getElementById('contenedor');
var resultado = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    method: "POST",
    dataType: "text",
    async: false,
    url: 'Aquí tu url',
    data: ´Aquí tus parámetros así :{parametro1 : '1',parametro2:'2'} sino lleva 
    omite esta linea o coloca null´,

}).responseText;

  contenido.innerHTML = resultado;
}
```

para que se cargue al comenzar la pagina debes ponerlo así:

```
window.onload = function Iniciar() {
Incluir();

}
```

**solución 3**

si por ultimo caso si incluyes esta linea `session_start();`  en el archivo php que incluyes y donde los incluye, es decir en el padre y en el hijo la solución es solo dejarla en un archivo, y debes dejarlo donde necesites usar esta variable global `$_SESSION`.

Answer (score -1):

posiblemente el problema está en la versión de PHP que estás utilizando. Si tienes PHP 7.2, bajalo a 7.1 que es una versión mucho más estable.

Además goza de la mayoría de los grandes avances que 7.2 especialmente la rapidez en la ejecución.

Yo tenía el mismo problema cuando cambie en cPanel de la versión 5.4 a 7.2, al cambiarla a 7.1 todo regresó a la normalidad.

Si no hay una razón poderosa para usar la versión 7.2 cambia a 7.1.

Ojalá esto ayude.

Comment: PHP 7.2 es ya una versión estable, la beta es la 7.3

Comment: el fallo es por que tiene código HTML ejecutándose antes del session_start() lo cual siempre va a generar ese error

Answer (score -1):

Tenia el mismo error!!
De manera local me funcionaba perfecto pero al momento de subirlo me presentaba algo similiar a esto:Warning: session_start(): Cannot start session when headers already sent... pero lo solucione actualizando la versión de PHP estaba utilizando 7.3 y baje a 7.1 y así es como pude solucionar el error.