# Warning: session_start(): Cannot start session when headers already sent in

Tags: php, mysql, session

Estoy en la parte de sesiones y estoy haciendo el archivo para proteger los `logins` al inicias la página pero tengo los errores de php que no se como solucionarlo espero que me puedan ayudar, que son los siguientes:

> Warning: session_start(): Cannot start session when headers already
>   sent in /storage/ssd3/544/9597544/public_html/php/seguridad.php on
>   line 4 Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION in
>   /storage/ssd3/544/9597544/public_html/php/seguridad.php on line 6
>   Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /storage/ssd3/544/9597544/public_html/php/datos.php:1) in
>   /storage/ssd3/544/9597544/public_html/php/seguridad.php on line 7**

```
<?php 
   error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
session_start(); //Inicia la sesión
//COMPRUEBA QUE EL USUARIO ESTA AUTENTIFICADO
if (!$_SESSION ){ //si no existe, envio a la página de autentificacion
header("Location:../index.html");
//ademas salgo de este script
exit();
}
?>
```

Comment: Aquí esta la respuesta a tu pregunta https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/157372/session-start-cannot-start-session-when-headers-already-sent

Comment: Saludos! pongo en mis demas archivos al inicion el session_start y me sale el mismo problema y en este esta al inicio para iniciar la session que me puedes aconsejar?

Comment: lo colocaste tal cual en la respuesta de la otra publicación?

Comment: sip esya exactamente igual

Comment: pero me sale el mismo error nada mas cambiendo la ubicacion de error+

Comment: Solucionado amigo

Comment: muhcas gracias amigo