# Warning: session_start(): Cannot start session when headers already sent in /storage/ssd4/158/9856158/public_html/sapd/index.php on line 3

Tags: php, php7

Mi error es este. Si quieren pasarse por la web de error es [americanzone.gq/sapd](http://americanzone.gq/sapd). Les pido ayuda, gracias  de ante mano

> Warning: session_start(): Cannot start session when headers already sent in /storage/ssd4/158/9856158/public_html/sapd/index.php on line 3

**Principal.php**

```
<?php 

session_start(); 
error_reporting(0); 
include_once('../kev/pdo.php');

if(isset($_SESSION['k_username']))
{
    $query = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE Username = :usuario");
    $query->bindParam(':usuario', $_SESSION[k_username], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->execute();

    while($row = $query->fetch())
    {
        $name = $row['Username'];
        if($row['Faccion'] != 1)
        {
            session_destroy();
            echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location="../index.php";</script>';
        }   
    }
}
else echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location="../sapd/index.php";</script>';

?>    

<?php 

    session_start(); 
    error_reporting(0); 
    include_once('../kev/pdo.php');

    if(isset($_SESSION['k_username']))
    {
        $query = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE Username = :usuario");
        $query->bindParam(':usuario', $_SESSION[k_username], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->execute();

        while($row = $query->fetch())
        {
            $name = $row['Username'];
            if($row['Faccion'] != 1)
            {
                session_destroy();
                echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location="../index.php";</script>';
            }   
        }
    }

    ?>
```

Es decir, invoco a ***principal.php*** desde ***index.php*** en donde no se puede iniciar sesión por cabeceras ya enviadas aún siendo la primer instrucción que ejecuto en cada invocación del método *session_start()*.

Comment: esta pregunta esta duplicada, aquí la solución https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/157372/session-start-cannot-start-session-when-headers-already-sent

Comment: No, son diferentes errores. En el otro dicen que es por una div pero el mio no tiene div y el sessio_start() esta al inicio

Comment: sigues teniendo un espacio en blanco

Comment: Como espacio en blanco?

Comment: Asegúrate de que no hay un espacio en blanco, salto de línea, tabulador o carácter escondido antes de la apertura `<?php`. Si el código compartido es en un fichero que se carga desde otro fichero, asegúrate de que el otro fichero no escribe nada antes de cargar éste. La raíz del error es la misma que en la otra pregunta, es sólo cuestión de encontrar dónde.

Comment: Por cierto. Remirando el código, parece que tienes lo mismo repetido 2 veces. El segundo `session_start()` lanzará el mensaje que dices porque se ha escrito antes (en el primer bloque, además del espacio en blanco de separación entre los dos bloques de PHP).

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [session\_start(): Cannot start session when headers already sent](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/157372/session-start-cannot-start-session-when-headers-already-sent)

Answer (score 0):

Elimina el espacio en blanco debería quedar asi:

```
 <?php
    session_start();
     ?>
```

Y elimina el segundo inicio

Comment: Los espacios dentro de las llaves `<?php ... ?>` no se mandan como salida. Lo que habría que hacer es eliminar los espacios de antes de la llave de comienzo `<?php`.