# error "session_start(): Cannot start session when headers already sent" al subir página al host

Tags: php

Tengo un error que se me genera ahora que tengo la pagina web subida en el `host`, pero cuando estuve trabajando en `localhost`, me funcionó la pagina normalmente

> Warning: session_start(): Cannot start session when headers already sent in /storage/ssd2/242/10438242/public_html/Jomar/users_control/controller/ControlAsisController.php on line 12

Para contextualizar, tengo varios controladores, en uno de ellos es donde hago el respectivo login, este controlador es `AdminController`, entonces hago un `session_start()` en el constructor de `AdminController` y en el método del login ya creo la variable, teniendo en cuenta esto, pues en el `AdminController` funciona con normalidad el `session` pero cuando voy a ir a otra pagina que llame a otro controlador, en este caso `ControlAsisController` pues me lanza el error, pero yo tengo hecho el `session_start()` en el constructor de ese también, entonces no entiendo que es lo que pasa, sí alguien me puede ayudar, se lo agradezco, espero que sea entendible.

Adjunto la parte del código donde hago el `session_start()`

`AdminController.php`

```
class AdminController{

    public function __construct(){
        $action = isset($_GET["action"]) ? $_GET["action"] : "todos";

        session_start();

        if($action == "enviarCorreoMail" || $action == "enviarCorreo" || $action == "generarCodigo"){
            $this->login();
        }else{
            if(method_exists($this, $action)){
                $this->$action();
            }else{
                $this->error();
            }
        }

    }
```

`ControlAsisController.php`

```
class ControlAsisController{
    public function __construct(){
        $action = isset($_GET["action"]) ? $_GET["action"] : "todos";
        session_start();
        if(!isset($_SESSION["login"]) || !$_SESSION["login"]){
            include '../views/administrador/login.php';
            return;
        }
        if(method_exists($this, $action)){
            $this->$action();
        }else{
            $this->error();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Posible duplicado de [session\_start(): Cannot start session when headers already sent](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/157372/session-start-cannot-start-session-when-headers-already-sent)

Comment: @Aprendiz en ese el error es por no definir bien el `session` y está trabajando en `localhost`, en mi caso es distinto, en `localhost` funciona normal, pero lo subo al `host`y me sale ese error

Comment: Sumando a lo que expuso Andres que es correcto. La session se va a crear automaticamente, por lo tanto no es necesario que la llames, menos dentro de una funcion. Si por algun caso de uso particular necesitas crearla manualmente, que sea tu primer linea de codigo.

Comment: Sumando a lo que expuso Andres que es correcto. La session se va a crear automaticamente, por lo tanto no es necesario que la llames, menos dentro de una funcion. Si por algun caso de uso particular necesitas crearla manualmente, que sea tu primer linea de codigo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Es muy probable que estés imprimiendo algún contenido antes de que llamar a:

```
session_start();
```

Trata de colocarlo al inicio de la ejecución.

Comment: Ah, vale, sí, lo tenía en el constructor porque es lo primero que se ejecuta, pero no sé que pasó, ahora sí funciona, gracias

Comment: esa era la idea de la pregunta que ya fue respondida @DaxTter77 si la hubieras checado ahi dan la misma indicación

Comment: @Aprendiz Pero pues, como está dentro de un html y este documento es solamente php, entonces pues ahí entra la diferencia, además pues lo primero que uno se fija es en la marcada, entonces, no coincidia con lo mio, igual, disculpa