# Error al inciar sesion en PHP

Tags: php

El error que me manda es el siguiente:

> session_start(): Cannot start session when headers already sent

Comprendo que ese error aparece cuando ya se envió algún `output` antes que el `php`.

Mi proyecto funciona perfectamente de manera local pero al subirlo a un `host` me comenzó a mostrar ese error espero puedan ayudarme, el código que estoy usando es el siguiente:

```php
<?php
if(isset($_POST['entrar'])){
            $user = $_POST['user']; 
            $pass = $_POST['pass'];
            $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "nombreusuario", "password" ,"nombrebd") or die("error");

        $consulta="SELECT * FROM users WHERE user='$user' and password='$pass'";
        $resultado=mysqli_query($conn, $consulta) or die("error");
        $filas=mysqli_num_rows($resultado);
        if($filas>=1){
        session_start();
        $_SESSION["User"]=$_POST['user'];
        echo "<META HTTP-EQUIV = 'REFRESH' CONTENT = '0; URL = Reconocimiento.php'>";
        }
        else {
    echo "<META HTTP-EQUIV = 'REFRESH' CONTENT = '0; URL = index.html'>";
        echo "error";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Me parece que esta línea:: `session_start();` debe ir a la misma altura que tu etiqueta de apertura de PHP, quedando así: `<?php session_start();`

Comment: Posible duplicado de [session\_start(): Cannot start session when headers already sent](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/157372/session-start-cannot-start-session-when-headers-already-sent)

Comment: Lo que dice el compañero es correcto

Comment: @Aprendiz colocarla justo debajo también funciona normalmente, por lo menos a mi sí

Answer (score 0):

El inicio de sesion con **session_start();** se debe poner al principio del código, justo después de abrir la etiqueta de php `<?php`

Puedes abrir tantas etiquetas de php como quieras y cerrarlas en un mismo código. Es decir, puedes escribir al principio del código `<?php session_start(); ?>` y luego más abajo volver abrir otra etiqueta **php** escribiendo `<?php` para seguir trabajando el código, y así tantas veces como quieras.

Para el buen uso de **session_start();** y del trabajo con sesiones y variables de sesion, la documentación oficial de php está muy bien explicada:  [Documentacion oficial](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.session-start.php).

Answer (score 0):

Cuando estás trabajando en `localhost` desde tu ordenador, el lugar donde lo pones puede que no presente problemas, pero en el momento de subirlo a un `host` sí es más exigente en esos aspectos, entonces, deberías colocarlo el `session_start()` al principio del documento, en este caso que parece que es solamente código `php`, colócalo antes del primer `if` y después de la etiqueta `<?php`, que quedaría así

```
<?php
session_start(); //Lo mueves a aquí
if(isset($_POST['entrar'])){
            $user = $_POST['user']; 
            $pass = $_POST['pass'];
            $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "nombreusuario", "password" ,"nombrebd") or die("error");

        $consulta="SELECT * FROM users WHERE user='$user' and password='$pass'";
        $resultado=mysqli_query($conn, $consulta) or die("error");
        $filas=mysqli_num_rows($resultado);
        if($filas>=1){
        $_SESSION["User"]=$_POST['user'];
        echo "<META HTTP-EQUIV = 'REFRESH' CONTENT = '0; URL = Reconocimiento.php'>";
        }
        else {
    echo "<META HTTP-EQUIV = 'REFRESH' CONTENT = '0; URL = index.html'>";
        echo "error";
        }
    }
?>
```

Espero que sea de ayuda, saludos!!

Answer (score 0):

Mi respuesta es basicamente la que ya te han dado [Deivid_41](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/285565/353184) o [DaxTter77](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/285569/353184) pero voy a añadir un matiz.

Tiene que estar **al principio del flujo completo de código**, si este código es llamado con un import o require o es un extracto y falta alguna cosa, también tiene que estar antes. Es decir:
Si tu flujo comienza en un "index.php" y esto está en otro fichero, en una función o donde sea, el bloque

```php
<?php
session_start();

[...]
```

debe estar al principio de ese "index.php".

Lo que dices de que en local te funciona me parece bastante inverosimil debido a que desde que existen las sesiones han funcionado de la misma manera, si no están en la primera linea del flujo, simplemente no funciona.

Para comprobar si la sesión se creo correctamente, la funcion session_start devuelve un booleano a si que te recomiendo cambiar el bloque anterior por este:

```php
<?php
if (!session_start()) throw new Exception("No se ha podido iniciar la sesión PhP");

[...]
```