# Error de session_start(): en Webhost000

Tags: php, php7, login, session, hosting

Recién he subido mi proyecto a hosting gratuito **webhost000** en el cual inicio sesión con usuario y contraseña. Cuándo trabajaba de forma local no había problema, pero ahora me arroja estos errores al iniciar sesión y no me muestra el nombre de usuario en el panel de inicio:

> Warning: session_start(): Cannot start session when headers already
>   sent in /storage/ssd3/123/10747123/public_html/panel.php on line 40
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION in
>   /storage/ssd3/123/10747123/public_html/panel.php on line 41

Mi código de inicio de sesión es el siguiente:

```
<?php
session_start();
require 'database.php';
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as contar FROM registros where email = 
'$email' and password = '$password'";
$bdconect = mysqli_query($conectar,$query);
$parametros = mysqli_fetch_array($bdconect);
if($parametros['contar']>0){
$_SESSION['username'] = $email;
header("location: ../panel.php");
}else {
echo'<script type="text/javascript">
alert("Usuario y/o Contraseña Incorrecos");
window.location.href="../login.php";
</script>';
}
?>
```

El siguiente es código que incluyo en el inicio de sesión:

```
<?php
    **session_start();
    $sesion = $_SESSION['username'];** Los errores me los marca aquí:
    if(!isset($sesion)){
        header("location: login.php");
    }else{
        echo "<center><h4> BIENVENIDO $sesion </h></center><br>";
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Donde haces el `session_start()` es un documento solo de php y la pusiste al inicio del documento?

Comment: Lo tengo en un cuerpo de html y lo puse debajo de mi header y así me funcionaba de forma loca.

Comment: ponlo totalmente arriba, apenas abras el html

Comment: ¿Podrías poner el nombre de los archivos PHP que estás compartiendo? Intuyo que el primero no es `login.php` y el segundo es `panel.php`. El problema es que si incluyes el segundo tras haber enviado HTML al navegador no podrás iniciar sesión. ¿Podrías compartir también el PHP en el que incluyes al `panel.php`?

Comment: Esta pregunta ya quedó resuelta, muchas gracias Oscar

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Trata esto

```
<?php
@session_start();
require 'database.php';
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as contar FROM registros where email = 
'$email' and password = '$password'";
$bdconect = mysqli_query($conectar,$query);
$parametros = mysqli_fetch_array($bdconect);
if($parametros['contar']>0){
$_SESSION['username'] = $email;
header("location: ../panel.php");
}else {
echo'<script type="text/javascript">
alert("Usuario y/o Contraseña Incorrecos");
window.location.href="../login.php";
</script>';
}
?>

<?php
    @session_start();
    $sesion = $_SESSION['username'];
    if(!isset($sesion)){
        header("location: login.php");
    }else{
        echo "<center><h4> BIENVENIDO $sesion </h></center><br>";
    }
    ?>
```

PHP soporta un operador de control de errores: el signo de arroba (@). Cuando se antepone a una expresión en PHP, cualquier mensaje de error que pueden ser generado por esa expresión será ignorado.

Si se ha establecido una función controladora de errores personalizada con set_error_handler() entonces todavía será llamada, pero este controlador de errores personalizado puede (y debe) llamar a error_reporting() el cual devolverá 0 cuando la llamada que provocó el error fue precedida por el signo @.

Si la propiedad track_errors está activada, cualquier mensaje de error generado por la expresión será guardada en la variable $php_errormsg. Esta variable se sobrescribe en cada error, así que se debe comprobar antes si se desea utilizar.

Nota: El operador @ trabaja sólo sobre expresiones. Una simple regla de oro es: si se puede tomar el valor de algo, entonces se le puede anteponer el operador @. Por ejemplo, puede anteponerse a variables, a llamadas a funciones e includes, constantes y así sucesivamente. No puede anteponerse a definiciones de función o clase, ni a estructuras condicionales como if y foreach, y así sucesivamente.

*"Advertencia**

En la actualidad, el operador de prefijo "@" para control de errores deshabilitará incluso el reporte de errores en casos de fallos críticos que terminarán la ejecución del script. Entre otras cosas, esto quiere decir que si se usa "@" para eliminar los errores de una cierta función y ésta no se encuentra disponible o ha sido escrita de forma incorrecta, el script se detendrá en ese punto sin indicación de por qué.

Comment: Listo, pero me arroja variable indefinida en $sesion = $_SESSION['username'];                           Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION in /storage/ssd3/123/10747123/public_html/panel.php on line 41

Comment: Aplicarle un echo al $_SESSION['username']; y revisa si tiene datos, si no tiene dato eso quiere decir que tu consulta no esta trayendo nada de informa

Comment: Y creo que tienes que abrir otro tema por que este ya quedo solucionado lol

Comment: Según lo que estás diciendo, veo que dice que ignora el error que genere cierta expresión, por lo tanto el error sigue estando ahí, y de ahí el error consiguiente que sle

Comment: No es recomendable silenciar los errores

Comment: @Aprendiz es que hay session_start() que están chocando o hay mas de un session_start() en el mismo documento y no representa un problema grabe, y por esa misma razón puse una nota, para que se contemple.

Comment: @gama984 he de darle la razón a Aprendiz, el error inicial no es por que existan múltiples `session_start`, es por que esta enviando el cuerpo de la petición antes que las cabeceras. Tapar bajo la alfombra el problema no es una solución, es una pésima idea y seguramente ` $_SESSION['username'];` no esté definida por qué no se enviaron las cabeceras de session y no a podido ser recuperada/creada la variable de sesion.

Answer (score 0):

algunas veces hay solo que aprender a leer.  [motivo del error](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/157372/session-start-cannot-start-session-when-headers-already-sent)

## segunda corrección

no puedes asignarle a una variable el valor de otra sin asignar!

```
    session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
        header("location: login.php");
    }else{
        echo "<center><h4> BIENVENIDO $sesion </h></center><br>";
    }
```

Comment: marcastes una pregunta como duplicada y luego la respondes, lo ideal es que cuando veas que es diferente elimines tu reporte

Answer (score 0):

Al momento de hacer el `session_start()` este siempre debe ir arriba del todo del documento, por lo tanto ya que me dices que el código `php` está en un `html`, carga lo del `html` e impide ejecutar el `session_start()` por lo tanto ponlo así

```
<?php session_start() ?>
<html>
<head></head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Comment: No entendiste, no debe ir arriba del  html, sino al principio del documento php antes de que se empiece a enviar el cuerpo de la peticion, tu respuesta seguira dando error.

Comment: Pero el dice que el tiene el código `php` en un cuerpo html

Comment: El cuerpo de una peticion http y el cuerpo de un html son cosas diferentes, `session_start` envia [Cabeceras HTTP](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers) que son enviadas al navegador antes de enviar el cuerpo o respuesta. Para usar sesiones basadas en cookies, session_start() debe ser llamada antes de imprimir cualquier cosa en el navegador.

Comment: Ya, pero sí cargas un html antes que un `session_start()` no te va a dejar, por lo tanto, sí se pone totalmente arriba del documento, y se abre el html o justo debajo de la etiqueta, pues debería dejar, yo tuve un error similar

Comment: No entendi que me quieres decir exactamente. Fijate en el codigo que pusiste, `<html>
<?php session_start() ?>` esto esta mal, en todo caso deberia ser `<?php session_start() ?><html>` si quieres podemos continuar en el chat para no alargar mas los comentarios [chat]

Comment: Dale, es bueno aprender, en todo caso no sería lo mismo, la etiqueta `<html>` como tal solamente es para dar inicio, por lo tanto no estaría cargando nada

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98283/discussion-between-daxtter77-and-xerif).