# Ayuda $_SESSION en php

Tags: php

Hola Buenas Lo que no entiendo es que en otros proyectos que he descargado de internet los $_SESSION funciona perfectamente, pero cuando lo intento en mi codigo no funciona he intentado con SESSION_START();
ob_start(); en los php y en los html pero no me ha funcionado lo que intento es que se haga un envio de un formulario,quisiera que salga su nombre que puso y el correo pero no funciona

```
// Comiendo de la sesión
session_start();
// Guardar datos de sesión
$_SESSION["usuario"] = "Peter";

echo "Sesión iniciada y establecido nombre de usuario!" . "<br>";
?>
<a href="segundo.php">Segundo!</a>
```

EL PHP

```
// Continuamos la sesión
session_start();
// Devolver los valores de sesión
echo "Nombre de usuario: " . $_SESSION["usuario"]
```

Este seria un ejemplo parecido cuando lo subo a un servidor no funca en localhost si pero no en otros PORFAVOR si alguien sabe otra forma de pasar $_SESSION

Comment: YA LO SOLUCIONE FAVOR DE NO COMENTAR PARA LOS QUE TIENEN EL MISMO PROBLEMA ES QUE TIENEN QUE USAR OB_START(); al principio de tu html y al final poner ob_end_flush();

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [session\_start(): Cannot start session when headers already sent](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/157372/session-start-cannot-start-session-when-headers-already-sent)