# Recibo un error al procesar un php llamado desde otro

Tags: php, mysql

Por favor quien podrá decirme por qué me aparece éste error a pesar que sí se procesa la información:

**WARNING**: session_start(): Cannot start session when headers already sent in pagina_insertar_pago.php on line 3

**WARNING**: Cannot modify header information  - headers already sent by pagina_insertar_pago.php on line 7

A pesar que aparece el error la información se procesa completamente, por lo que no pareciera un error grave pero quizá estoy usando más recurso del servidor que no necesito, es lo que no sé.

He leído en varias publicaciones que el session_start debe estar siempre al inicio del código, y de hecho lo está.

**ARCHIVO: PAGINA_INSERTAR_PAGO.PHP**

```
<?php 

    session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION["usuario_logueado"])){

    header('location: form/login.php');
    }
?>



<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Grabando Cobro</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>

<?php
    date_default_timezone_set("America/Santiago");
    $busqueda_fecha= date($_POST["fecha_comp"]);
    $busqueda_inmueble= $_POST["inmueble"];

    $busqueda_nrocomp= $_POST["nro_comp"];
    $busqueda_monto= $_POST["monto"];
    $busqueda_observaciones= $_POST["observaciones"];
    $busqueda_banco= $_POST["banco"];
    $busqueda_cuenta= $_POST["cuenta"];

    $forma= $_POST["forma"];
    if ($forma<>"TRANSFERENCIA BANCARIA"){
        $busqueda_nrocomp=$forma;
        $busqueda_banco="0000";
        $busqueda_cuenta="00000000000000000000";
    }

    $tipo="RC";
    //date_default_timezone_set('UTC -4,00');
    //$fechaActual = date_format(time(),"Y-m-d");
    $fechaActual= date('Ymd');

  $host_name = 'db5000283847.hosting-data.io';
  $database = 'dbs277133';
  $user_name = 'dbu82772';
  $passwordc = 't6cLLBMQtave8e2/';
  $dbh = null;

  try {

    /*$dbh=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=trinitarias', 'root', '');*/
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$host_name; dbname=$database;", $user_name, $passwordc);

    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $dbh->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");


  //AQUI TRABAJO ES COLOCANDO EN UNA VARIABLE LLAMADA NUEVOSALDO EL SALDO FINAL DESPUES DE REGISTRAR ESTE PAGO

    try {
    $sql="SELECT id_inmueble,saldo_inmueble,correo_usuario,propietario from inmuebles where id_inmueble= :apartamento";
    $resultadosaldo=$dbh->prepare($sql);
    $resultadosaldo->execute(array(":apartamento"=>$busqueda_inmueble));
    $nuevosaldo=0;
    while($fila=$resultadosaldo->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $nombre_propietario=$fila['propietario'];
        $correo_usuario=$fila['correo_usuario'];
        $saldoanterior=$fila['saldo_inmueble'];
        $nuevosaldo=$saldoanterior-$busqueda_monto;
        //echo "El saldo anterior es: " . $saldoanterior . ", y el nuevo saldo es: " . $nuevosaldo;

    }
    $resultadosaldo->closecursor();
    }catch(exception $ss){

        die('Error en select saldo: ' . $ss->getmessage());
    }
//CULMINA LA OPERACION DEL CALCULO DEL NUEVO SALDO


//AQUI TRABAJO ES COLOCANDO EN UNA VARIABLE LLAMADA NUEVOCORRELATIVO EL NRO DEL RECIBO PARA REGISTRAR ESTE PAGO

  try {
    $sql="SELECT ult_num_doc from correlativos where tipo_doc= :tipo";
    $resultadocorrelativo=$dbh->prepare($sql);
    $resultadocorrelativo->execute(array(":tipo"=>$tipo));
    while($fila=$resultadocorrelativo->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $correlativoanterior=$fila['ult_num_doc'];
        $nuevocorrelativo=$correlativoanterior+1;
        //echo "El correlativo anterior es: " . $correlativoanterior . ", y el nuevo correlativo es: " . $nuevocorrelativo . "<br>" . $fechaActual;

    }
    $resultadocorrelativo->closecursor();
    }catch(exception $s){

        die('Error en select: ' . $s->getmessage());
    }
//CULMINA LA OPERACION DEL NUMERO DE RECIBO 

//AQUI TRABAJO ES ACTUALIZANDO EL SALDO EN LA TABLA INMUEBLES

  try {
    $sql="UPDATE inmuebles set saldo_inmueble=$nuevosaldo, fec_ult_saldo=$fechaActual where id_inmueble= :apartamento";
    $resultadosaldo=$dbh->prepare($sql);
    $resultadosaldo->execute(array(":apartamento"=>$busqueda_inmueble));
    $resultadosaldo->closecursor();
    }catch(exception $b){

        die('Error en inmuebles: ' . $b->getmessage());
    }
//CULMINA LA OPERACION DE ACTUALIZACION DE SALDO DEL INMUEBLE   


//AQUI TRABAJO ES ACTUALIZANDO EL CORRELATIVO EN LA TABLA CORRELATIVOS

  try 
      {
    $sql="UPDATE correlativos set ult_num_doc=$nuevocorrelativo, ult_fec_doc=$fechaActual where tipo_doc= :tipo";
    $resultadocorrelativo=$dbh->prepare($sql);
    $resultadocorrelativo->execute(array(":tipo"=>$tipo));
    $resultadocorrelativo->closecursor();

       }
      catch(exception $i)
       {

        die('Error en correlativos: ' . $i->getmessage());
       }
//CULMINA LA OPERACION DEL NUMERO DE RECIBO 



    $sql="INSERT INTO pagos_por_aprobar (fec_comp, 
                                         id_inmueble,
                                         monto_comp,
                                         num_comp,
                                         observaciones,
                                         cod_banco,
                                         codigo_cuenta, tipo_doc, num_doc, saldo_inmueble, fec_proc)
                                         values
                                         (:fec,
                                         :inm,
                                         :mon,
                                         :nro,
                                         :obs,
                                         :ban,
                                         :cue,
                                         :tipodoc,
                                         :numdoc,
                                         :saldofinal,
                                         :fecproc)";


    $resultado=$dbh->prepare($sql);


    $resultado->execute(array(":fec"=>$busqueda_fecha,
                              ":inm"=>$busqueda_inmueble,
                              ":mon"=>$busqueda_monto,
                              ":nro"=>$busqueda_nrocomp,
                              ":obs"=>$busqueda_observaciones,
                              ":ban"=>$busqueda_banco,
                              ":cue"=>$busqueda_cuenta,
                              ":tipodoc"=>$tipo,
                              ":numdoc"=>$nuevocorrelativo,
                              ":saldofinal"=>$nuevosaldo,
                              ":fecproc"=>$fechaActual));

    //COMENZANDO EL CODIGO PARA EL ENVIO DEL RECIBO

    //if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

    // Debes editar las próximas dos líneas de código de acuerdo con tus preferencias
        $email_to = $correo_usuario;
        $email_from = 'webmaster@trinitarias.crg-sistemas.com';
        //$email_to = $correo_usuario;
        $email_subject = "PAGO PROCESADO APTO: " . $busqueda_inmueble;

        // Aquí se deberían validar los datos ingresados por el usuario
        //if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||
        //!isset($_POST['last_name']) ||
        //!isset($_POST['email']) ||
        //!isset($_POST['telephone']) ||
        //!isset($_POST['comments'])) {

        //echo "<b>Ocurrió un error y el formulario no ha sido enviado. </b><br />";
        //echo "Por favor, vuelva atrás y verifique la información ingresada<br />";
        //die();
        //}
        $email_message = "RECIBO NRO: " . $nuevocorrelativo . "\r\n";
        $email_message .= "Hemos Recibido de: " . $nombre_propietario . "\r\n";
        $email_message .= "Inmueble: " . $busqueda_inmueble . "\r\n";
        $email_message .= "La Cantidad de Bss: " . $busqueda_monto . "\r\n";
        $email_message .= "Nro. de Comprobante: " . $busqueda_nrocomp . "\r\n";
        $email_message .= "desde el Banco: " . $busqueda_banco . "\r\n";
        $email_message .= "Recibido en la cuenta Nro: " . $busqueda_cuenta . "\r\n";
        $email_message .= "Saldo Anterior Bss: " . $saldoanterior . "\r\n";
        $email_message .= "Saldo Actual despúes de la operación Bss: " . $nuevosaldo . "\r\n";
        $email_replica = "condominiocrlastrinitarias@gmail.com";
        //$email_message .= "Teléfono: " . $_POST['telephone'] . "\n";
        $email_message .= "Comentarios: " . $busqueda_observaciones . "\r\n";


        // Ahora se envía el e-mail usando la función mail() de PHP
        $headers =  "From: ". $email_from . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "Cc: " . $email_replica . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "Reply-To: " . $email_replica . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();
        mail($email_to, $email_subject, utf8_decode($email_message), $headers);

        echo'<script type="text/javascript">
        alert("PAGO PROCESADO Y ENVIADO");
        window.location.href="../registrar_pago.php";
        </script>';

    }catch(Exception $e){

      echo "Error terminando el archivo: " . $e->getMessage();


   }
?>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [session\_start(): Cannot start session when headers already sent](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/157372/session-start-cannot-start-session-when-headers-already-sent)

Comment: Checa en la respuesta que te pase, debes dejarlo al inicio

Comment: @betam si, lo tengo en el inicio.