# PHP Warning: session_start(): Cannot start session when headers already sent in

Tags: php, apache

tengo el siguiente problema al usar la función session_start() 
**'PHP Warning:  session_start(): Cannot start session when headers already sent in'**, esto sucede a la hora de hacer el login, el problema es **que esto no sucedia en mi hosting anterior**, esto comenzó a pasar en mi nuevo hosting, utilizo la misma versión de PHP (7.2)

La verdad no sé que mas probar, probé con UTF8 sin BOM con BOM, pero nada cambió, lo que me llama la atención es que los mismos archivos IGUALES funcionan sin problemas en un hosting y en el otro no

Probé con php_flag output_buffering On y php_value output_buffering On y los 2 me causan error 500 internal

Este es el código y el error me lo da en la línea del session_start();

```
<?php

function filtro($datos){
    $datos = filter_var($datos, FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
    $datos = trim($datos);
    $datos = stripslashes($datos);
    $datos = htmlspecialchars($datos);
    return $datos;
}

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    require_once 'Conexion.php';
    $errorMsj = array();

    $Usuario = filtro($_POST['username']);
    $Contrasena = filtro($_POST['password']);

    if(strlen($Usuario) < 4) { $errorMsj[1] = 'El nombre de usuario ingresado es demaciado corto'; } elseif(strlen($Usuario) > 25) { $errorMsj[2] = 'El nombre de usuario ingresado es demaciado largo'; }
    if(strlen($Contrasena) < 6) { $errorMsj[3] = 'La contraseña ingresada es demaciado corta'; } elseif(strlen($Contrasena) > 35) { $errorMsj[4] = 'La contraseña ingresada es demaciado larga'; }

    $Contador = 0;
    $Errores = 0;
    while($Contador < 5) {
        if(isset($errorMsj[$Contador]) != '') {
            echo '<b style="color: red;"> &bull; '.$errorMsj[$Contador].'</b><br>';
            $Errores++;
        }
        $Contador++;
    }

    if($Errores == 0) {

        $ComprobarUsuario = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM Usuarios WHERE Name=? LIMIT 1");
        $data = [$Usuario];

        $ComprobarUsuario->execute($data);

        if($ComprobarUsuario->rowCount() == 1) {

            $VerificarContrasenia = $ComprobarUsuario->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $IdUsuario = (int) $VerificarContrasenia['id'];
            $hash = (string) $VerificarContrasenia['Password'];
            if(password_verify($Contrasena, $hash)) {
                echo '<b style="color: green;">Ingresaste de forma correcta</b>';
                
                session_start();
                $_SESSION['user_name'] = $Usuario;
                $_SESSION['ADM'] = $VerificarContrasenia['TipoUser'];

                $VerificarContrasenia = null;

                $pdo = null;
                $data = null;
                $IdUsuario = null;
                $hash = null;
                $Usuario = null;
                $Contrasena = null;
                $Errores = null;
                echo '<script>window.location="https://web.com/index.php";</script>';

            } else {
                echo '<b style="color: red;"> &bull; No existe ninguna cuenta con los datos ingresados</b>';
            }
        }
        else {
            echo '<b style="color: red;"> &bull; No existe ninguna cuenta con los datos ingresados</b>';
        }
    }
}
else {
    $errorMsj[0] = 'Error #1';
}

?>
```

Es importante destacar que este código se ejecuta al mandar el formulario de ingreso

Comment: Podrías subir tu código, así es muy dificil ayudarte

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [session\_start(): Cannot start session when headers already sent](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/157372/session-start-cannot-start-session-when-headers-already-sent)

Comment: Vi ese hilo pero no me funcionó

Comment: Debes ser mas claro por favor, si dices que lo revisaste entonces añade en tu pregunta que aplicaste basándote en el y que no funcionó

Comment: Es complicado ser claro con este error, porque estimo que es un error de configuración de algo, no del archivo, en el hilo que usted pasó están solucionando un problema en especifico, mi problema apareció al cambiar de hosting (y no es por el display_error)

Comment: No he trabajado con PDO, sin embargo, creo que deberias declarar session start en la parte superior de todo tu código

Comment: Si lo declaro en el comienzo del código también da el error, además que yo necesitaría que se inicie la sesión cuando los datos del login sean correctos. Si uncluyo if( !headers_sent() && '' == session_id() ) el error desaparece pero no me guarda las variables $_SESSION

Answer (score 2):

Lo pude solucionar agregándole un valor a 'output_buffering' en info.ini

Comment: ¿Y qué valor le agregaste?

Comment: El valor que le ingresé yo fue 4096

Comment: Eso debe ir en la respuesta, acuerdate para que alguien mas que lo consulte sepa que archivo modificar y que valor poner

Comment: No solucionaste el error, porque cuando cambies de servidor volverá a aparecer si el búfer de salida está desactivado. Entonces, solo aplicaste un parche.

Comment: Cuando cambie de servidor aplico nuevamente el valor de output_buffering en 4096 y listo, es la forma con la cual me funcionaba mi en el anterior servidor y me funciona ahora en este!

Comment: Debería ser la respuesta correcta. Gracias !

Answer (score 0):

Por lo general trabajo con Mysqli y nunca he tenido esos problemas, te dejo algo para que te des una idea

```
<?php
$alert = '';
session_start();
 if(!empty($_SESSION['active']))
{
header('location: inicio.php');
}else{
 if(!empty($_POST))
  {
  if (empty($_POST['usuario']) || empty($_POST['password'])) 
  {
   $alert = 'Ingrese su usuario y contraseña por favor';
   }else {
   require_once "ConexionALOGIN.php";
   $usuario = ($_POST['usuario']);
    $password = sha1($_POST['password']);
    $query = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM t_usuarios WHERE usuario = 
   '$usuario' AND password = '$password'");
    $result = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    if ($result > 0) {
    $data = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
    $_SESSION['active'] = true;
    $_SESSION['id_usuario'] = $data['id_usuario'];
    $_SESSION['nombre'] = $data['nombre'];
    $_SESSION['fechaNacimiento'] = $data['fechaNacimiento'];
    $_SESSION['email'] = $data['email'];
    $_SESSION['usuario'] = $data['usuario'];
    $_SESSION['password'] = $data['password'];
    $_SESSION['rol'] = $data['rol'];
    header('location: inicio.php');
 }else{
    $alert ='Datos incorrectos';
    session_destroy();
 }
  }
  }
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: Mas que dejarle un script enorme y sin comentarios, lo ideal es que por lo menos le explicaras como usar esto y como le soluciona el problema

Comment: Lo leí entero al script y es simple como el mío, pero si yo subo eso a mi hosting también me dará el error PHP Warning: session_start(): Cannot start session when headers already sent in

Comment: Debes controlar que no haya absolutamente ningún tipo de salida (echo, print...) o de código HTML antes de session_start();

Y eso no es solo referente al script en cuestión, sino que debes tomarlo en cuenta muy especialmente cuando concatenas archivos mediante include o require. El mensaje de error indica que están interviniendo los archivos login.php e index.php. Si por ejemplo tú incluyes código HTML en login.php o sacas algo por pantalla y luego usas session_start() en index.php vas a tener este tipo de errores.