# session_start (): No se puede iniciar la sesión cuando los encabezados ya se enviaron en login.php en la línea 9

Tags: php, html, sql

no me deja iniciar sesión como puedo arreglarlo, ya intente todo y nada solo me aparece esto en la línea 9 este es mi codigo :

> Advertencia : session_start (): No se puede iniciar la sesión cuando
> los encabezados ya se enviaron en
> /storage/ssd1/273/15621273/public_html/Proyecto_Final/login.php

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/materialize.min.css"  media="screen,projection"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<?php
session_start();
session_id();   
error_reporting(0);


$varsession = $_SESSION['user_id'];

if ($varsession == null || $varsession = '') {
 header("Location:sesion.php");
 die();
}


  require 'database.php';

  if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
    $records = $conn->prepare('SELECT id, nombre,password,usuario,telefono,fecha FROM user WHERE id = :id');

    $records->bindParam(':id', $_SESSION['user_id']);
    $records->execute();
    $results = $records->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $user = null;

    if (count($results) > 0) {
      $user = $results;
    }
  }
?> 


<?php require 'partials/header.php' ?>

    <?php if(!empty($user)): ?>
<style>
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color:#F7DC6F ;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: #111;
  color: #333;
}
/* Full-width input fields */
input[type=text], input[type=password] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Set a style for all buttons */
button {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
}

button:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

/* Extra styles for the cancel button */
.cancelbtn {
  width: auto;
  padding: 10px 18px;
  background-color: #f44336;
}

/* Center the image and position the close button */
.imgcontainer {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 24px 0 12px 0;
  position: relative;
}

img.avatar {
  width: 40%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.container {
  padding: 16px;
}

span.psw {
  float: right;
  padding-top: 16px;
}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  z-index: 1; 
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%; 
  background-color:#AED6F1;

}

/* Modal Content/Box */
.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: 5% auto 15% auto; /* 5% from the top, 15% from the bottom and centered */
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%; /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */

}

/* The Close Button (x) */
.close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 25px;
  top: 0;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Add Zoom Animation */
.animate {
  -webkit-animation: animatezoom 0.6s;
  animation: animatezoom 0.6s
}

@-webkit-keyframes animatezoom {
  from {-webkit-transform: scale(0)} 
  to {-webkit-transform: scale(1)}
}
  
@keyframes animatezoom {
  from {transform: scale(0)} 
  to {transform: scale(1)}
}

/* Change styles for span and cancel button on extra small screens */
@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  span.psw {
     display: block;
     float: none;
  }
  .cancelbtn {
     width: 100%;
  }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<center>
  

<ul>
  <br>
  <li>.<a href="logout.php" class="waves-effect  purple btn-small">Cerrar</a></li><br><br>
  <li>.<a  onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'" class="waves-effect red btn-small">Informacion</a></li><br>
  <li><br></li>
</ul>
</center>



<div id="id01" class="modal">
  
  <form class="modal-content animate" action="/action_page.php" method="post">
    <div class="imgcontainer">
   
    </div>

    <div class="container">
    
<label>NOMBRE</label>
  <input  type="tetx" name="" value="<?php echo $user['nombre']?>" readonly  ><br><br>
<label>USUARIO</label>
  <input type="tetx" name="" value="<?php echo $user['usuario']?>" readonly><br><br>
<label>TELEFONO</label>
  <input type="tetx" name="" value="<?php echo $user['telefono']?>" readonly><br><br>
 <label>FECHA DE NACIMIENTO</label> 
  <input type="tetx" name="" value="<?php echo $user['fecha']?>" readonly><br><br>
  <center>
    <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="cancelbtn">Cerrar</button>
  </center>
    </div>

   
    </div>
  </form>
</div>

<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('id01');

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>


<style>
body {
  font-family: Arial;
  color: white;
}

.split {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  position: fixed;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.left {
  left: 0;
  background-color: #1ABC9C;
}

.right {
  right: 0;
  background-color:  #CD6155;
}

.centered {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}

.centered img {
  width: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.text{
  font-size: 30px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="split left">
  <div class="centered">
    <img class="" src="https://triquinet.com/wp-content/uploads/elementor/thumbs/iconopreparateparavender-nvyxpczx5evbclof2xeckw7f7oh5pn7ynx4ezb5xwy.png" alt="Avatar woman"><br><br>
    <h2 class="text">Vender</h2>
    <a href="vender.php" class="waves-effect orange btn-small">Aceptar</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="split right">
  <div class="centered">
    <img class="" src="https://img.icons8.com/cotton/452/shopping.png" alt="Avatar man">
    <h2 class="text">Comprar</h2>
  <a href="comprar.php" class="waves-effect green btn-small">Aceptar</a>
  </button>
  </div>
</div>
     
</body>
</html> 



<script type="text/javascript">
   document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.sidenav');
    var instances = M.Sidenav.init(elems, options);
  });

  // Or with jQuery

  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.sidenav').sidenav();
  });
</script>
    
 <?php else: ?>

    <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes colocar las funciones de sesión al inicio del código.
Tomé de referencia esta respuesta: [session_start(): Cannot start session when headers already sent](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/157372/session-start-cannot-start-session-when-headers-already-sent)

```
<?php
session_start();
session_id();   
error_reporting(0);
?>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/materialize.min.css"  media="screen,projection"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/materialize.min.js"></script>

[...]
```